# Single-particle states in statistical distributions and the significance of Probability Distribution Function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, bosons

This is a very basic doubt from Statistical Mechanics which I haven't been able to resolve yet.

Suppose we take into account only single-particle states for a system, and we wish to look at the various possible scenarios with the help of Maxwell-Boltzmann, Fermi-Dirac, and Bose-Einstein probability distributions. I've read that $f(E)$ is the probability distribution function, which also represents the average number of particles in a given state. While deriving this for the Bose-Einstein (B-E) or Fermi-Dirac (F-D) distributions, we've seen that $f(E)$ saturates at $1$ for F-D, while it can tend to $\infty$ for a B-E distribution. But is this true for a single-particle state as well(not single state!)? Should $f(E)$ lie in $[0,1]$ alike for distinguishable particles, Bosons and Fermions? Should $f(E)$ still represent an average number of particles for a single-particle state, as it's now a fraction? Can someone provide a detailed explanation to help me kill this doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably correct your question. BE distribution starts from $\infty$ and asymptotically approaches 0 while FD starts at 1. Here is the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics#/media/File:Fermi-Dirac_Bose-Einstein_Maxwell-Boltzmann_statistics.svg) of the three statistics under discussion.

Probability distribution(in Statistical Mechanics) represents the average occupancy of states and not the number of particles in a state. Distribution function times the density of states gives the number density of particles (can be loosely thought of as the number of particles in the particular state)

These distribution arise because of the fundamental difference between two types of particles namely Fermions and Bosons. This is equally true for single-particle states as well, as in if you fill single-particle states with fermions, since only two particles(spin multiplicity) can occupy a state it is bound to follow FD distribution.

Comment: I totally agree with you, and the bounds of the graphs are such due to the temperature dependence, and I'm aware of it. The fundamental doubt that's been bugging me is that for B-E, $f(E)$ starts from $\infty$ at very low temperatures, so $f(E)$ can't surely represent probability of occupation in this case. So how is $f(E)$ different from the probability of occupation of a state? Also, shouldn't $f(E)$ saturate at 1 alike for all 3 types of objects for a single-particle state?

Comment: ahh... in strict mathematical term it is called a [Probability Density Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) and it can start from $\infty$ provided the area under the graph is unity. Just think of it as a weight function that adds weightage to the different possible level. I didnt understand the last question. Saturate to 1 where? At high energy levels? And is there any chance you are confusing single particle state with single particle system?

Comment: Single particle state is a state where only one particle is involved, and doesn't interact with other particles of the system, am I correct? It necessarily might not be a single-particle system. By saturation I mean that in general, for fermions, at very low temperatures, when the energy of the single-particle state is less than the fermi-energy at that temperature, then $f(E)$ for that distribution tends to $1$. This is obviously not the case for B-E, where at low temperatures, the graph clearly extends till $\infty$. You are correct in naming $f(E)$ as the Probability Density function.

Comment: But my doubt is that, on integrating the probability distribution function along with the degeneracies of the state(if any), I should get the total number of particles in that state, and not the probability of occupancy of that state. So, how should the normalized area be unity under the graph for $f(E)$? The question which I ask basically boils down to this- Is the Probability Distribution function same as the probability of occupancy for a single-particle state for Bosons, Fermions, and Distinguishable particles alike?

Comment: Oh okay, I think I get it now! Can you kindly just confirm if the probability density function actually becomes the probability of occupation(apparently it seems obvious to me!) for a single-particle state for all the 3 distributions as I've mentioned above? Thanks a lot, by the way!

Comment: Yes, the distribution function (although I find it weird, lets stick with the physics terminology) gives the probability(now that you mentioned it, a better word would be weightage, probability in conventional sense cant be greater than 1) of occupation of the various quantum levels of bound system in thermal equilibrium (it doesn't matter whether its a single particle state or not). Distribution function solely depends on the fundamental particles that is used to fill the states.

Comment: Furthur, $f(E)g(E)$ gives the Number Density of states, and the number of particles in states with energy between $E$ and $dE$ is given by $f(E)G(E)dE$, where $G(E)$ is the density of states that takes into account the geometry of the system, degeneracies, etc.

Comment: $f(E)$ tends to $\infty$ at very low temperatures for a B-E distribution. In that case, how can $f(E)$ possibly represent the probability of occupation of a quantum state?

Comment: In a single-particle state, the average is contributed to by only a single particle, and hence the average distribution actually becomes the probability of occupation of this state in this case. This is what I feel, kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes so Bosons do no follow Pauli exclusion Principle and so they tend to have maximum probability of occupying the ground state at very low temperature, this phenomena is called a condensate. Ohh... a single particle states have nothing to do with a single particle system. There can be any number of particles occupying single particle states, and this many particle quantum formalism is commonly called [Second quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization).

Comment: I'm just a beginner in Statistical Mechanics, but I believe that a single-particle state can only be occupied by one particle and many such single-particle states can be taken together to form a many-particle system, where each particle-state weakly interacts with the other! This is what I've read, but after this doubt of mine, I'm highly confused. Can you please add a detailed explanation, if you do have some time? It would be highly helpful.

Comment: I can't just relate $f(E)$ to the probability of occupation of a state, at least for Bosons.

Comment: Statistical Mechanics deals with 1) system with very large number of particles 2) In our case, system has to be essentially in thermal equilibrium. Now for a single particle system, Stat Mech simply cant be applied because neither of the two is satisfied(notion of temperature is still not clear when considering a single particle).

Comment: Distribution function just gives the weightage of occupation of each states. Say I have 10 states at increasing energy level (not particles). IF they the particles that is supposed to occupy these states are bosons they will follow BE distr. So at very low temperature the distribution is very high for low energy states, it means that the probability of the low lying energy states are much much higher compared to the higher energy states, ie the ground state will be occupied to a very large extend while the other 9 states will lie dormant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one thing, if I wish to find out the probability of occupation of a state, how would I go about finding it? This is because, $f(E_{i})$ would be equal to $\frac{n_{i}}{g_{i}}$, where $n_{i}$ is the number of particles in the $i^{th}$ state and $g_{i}$ is the number of degeneracies of the $i^{th}$ state.

Comment: Ok, I believe I get it now, $f(E)$ is basically going to be the weightage function for each possible state, and for a system of N particles, the probability of occupation of a single state would be $\frac{f(E_{i})g_{i}}{N}$. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: You are very welcome. Distribution function has nothing to do with neither the number of particles nor the degeneracy of states. It can be thought of as an inherent property of the system. The three standard distributions are MB, FD, and BE. I am sure you already know when these are supposed to be used. Density of States (DoS) is the guy who deals with number of particles, degeneracy, dimensions of the system, etc.

Comment: Yeah, the term $single-particle$ state sure was playing a mental game with me, I'm quite  relieved now to put it off!